# Setting focus order for wrapped components on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having trouble controlling the focus order when using custom components. Specifically, when I wrap an EditText with non-focusable components and then put two in a horizontal LinearLayout, only the first will receive focus. (I'm adding other features on top; the below code is an MRE.)

I've tried using nextFocusForward and nextFocusDown to set the focus order, which I've confirmed works correctly on raw EditTexts, but it doesn't on the custom view. I also tried passing along the attribute to the EditText, but that didn't work, either. I've also tried making my custom view focusable, but it doesn't receive the focus events (I think because the EditText receives them instead) and has the same issue.

edittext_wrapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        tools:text="test"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

EditTextWrapper.java:

```
public class EditTextWrapper extends LinearLayout {
    public EditTextWrapper(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.edittext_wrapper, this, true);
    }
}
```

activity_test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <com.....EditTextWrapper
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <com.....EditTextWrapper
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/right"
            />
        <com.....EditTextWrapper
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.....EditTextWrapper
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm expecting when the cursor is in the 2nd EditText and you press the next key on the keyboard that it goes to the 3rd one, but instead it goes to the 4th.

I suspect the reason manually setting the id for nextFocusDown didn't work is because I'm using the ID of my wrapper class which isn't focusable. I'm pretty unsure of what I should try next.

Answer (score -1):

I have checked that change your edittextwrapper.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/app_name"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    tools:text="test" />
```

And also you can use this for focus widgets

```
view.requestFocus();
```

Comment: The reason I have the LinearLayout is to group multiple elements together. I removed the other Views because it wasn't necessary in order to repro. Imagine that there's a TextView above the EditText.